# AngularFireList - Avoid reloading all data on subscription change - Angular5/Ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, ionic3, angularfire2

Good morning,

I have a problem when loading a list from firebase and rendering it to my view with AngularFire2.

Explanations:

I have in my page a function allowing to load a list of posts, and to map the posts to the user data, to then bind the whole list to the view :

Timeline.ts:

```
// Get the timeline data
getTimeline() {
    console.log('Get timeline data');
    this.loadingProvider.show();
    this.createUserData(); // create user data if accoutn just created
    this.dataProvider.getCurrentUser().valueChanges().subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = <any>user;
    });

    this.getUserFriends().then((friends) => {
      this.friends = friends;
    }).then(() => {
      this.dataProvider.getTimelinePost().valueChanges().subscribe((posts) => {
        console.log("Change in timeline");
        this.timelineData = posts.slice(0).reverse().map(p => {
          return this.checkPostData(p);
        });
        this.loadingProvider.hide();
      });

    });
  }

// Get the friend's user so we can display only the post who are relevants for the user
  getUserFriends() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.dataProvider.getFriends().valueChanges().subscribe((f) => {
        resolve(f)
      });
    });
  }

// Map post data with user's info such as avatar, etc
  checkPostData(currentPost) {
    let postedByFriend = this.checkIfPostedByFriend(currentPost);
    if (postedByFriend || currentPost.postBy === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
      this.dataProvider.getUser(currentPost.postBy).valueChanges().subscribe((user) => {
        currentPost.avatar = user.img;
        currentPost.name = user.name
      });
      //  Liked ?
      this.dataProvider.getLike(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((likes) => {
        currentPost.likes = likes.length;
        currentPost.isLike = this.checkIfPostIsLiked(likes);
      });
      //  Disliked ?
      this.dataProvider.getdisLike(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((dislikes) => {
        currentPost.dislikes = dislikes.length;
        currentPost.isdisLike = this.checkIfPostIsDislike(dislikes);
      });
      // Commented ?
      this.dataProvider.getComments(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((comments) => {
        currentPost.comments = comments.length;
        currentPost.isComment = this.checkIfPostIsCommented(comments);
      });
    }
    return currentPost;
}
```

Timeline.html :

```
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of timelineData">
    <ion-item >
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{item.avatar}}"  >
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.dateCreated | DateFormat}}</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{item.postText}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
    [...]
  </ion-card>
```

DataProvider.ts :

```
// Get Timeline post
  getTimelinePost(){
    return this.angularDb.list<any>('/timeline');
  }
```

My problem is the following: when I add a post to the timeline, it takes a few seconds because the Timeline.ts page reloads the entire list (which is normal because there is a subscription made with getTimeLinePost()). I would like to know if it is possible to detect only the last changes in my list to add them to the view and thus avoid reloading all the data.

I have already tried SnapshotChanges() and StateChange() but without success.

I noticed that when I add a post, the subscription is triggered twice :

> Change in timeline (2) timeline.ts:89:8

Addpost.ts code :

```
pushNewPost(url) {
    this.angularDb.list('timeline').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().toString(),
      postBy: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      postText: this.postText,
      image: url
    })
}
```

Versions used : 
    "@angular": "5.2.11",
    "angularfire2":"^5.0.0-rc.5-next",

Any idea for this ? Am I missing something?

thanks in advance

UPDATE :

I found an alternative that has less impact on rendering performance (on the view), but all data is still loaded when a change is triggered on the database:

```
    getTimeline() {
    console.log('Get timeline data');
    this.loadingProvider.show();
    this.createUserData();
    this.dataProvider.getCurrentUser().valueChanges().subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = <any>user;
    });

    this.getUserFriends().then((friends) => {
      this.friends = friends;
    }).then(() => {
      this.dataProvider.getTimelinePost().snapshotChanges().map(actions =>
        actions.map(a => ({ type: a.type, ...a.payload.val() }))
      ).subscribe(items => {
        this.checkPostData(items);
        this.loadingProvider.hide();
      });
    });
  }

  getUserFriends() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.dataProvider.getFriends().valueChanges().subscribe((f) => {
        resolve(f)
      });
    });
  }

  checkPostData(currentPost) {
   // Check if whe have a child added to the timeline
    if (this.timelineLoaded === true) {
      currentPost.forEach(p => {
        if (p.type === 'child_added') {
          this.mapPost(p);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.timelineData = [];
      currentPost.map(p => {
        return this.mapPost(p);
      });
    }
  }

  mapPost(currentPost) {
    let postedByFriend = this.checkIfPostedByFriend(currentPost);
    if (postedByFriend || currentPost.postBy === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
      this.dataProvider.getUser(currentPost.postBy).valueChanges().subscribe((user) => {
        currentPost.avatar = user.img;
        currentPost.name = user.name
      });
      //  Liked ?
      this.dataProvider.getLike(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((likes) => {
        currentPost.likes = likes.length;
        currentPost.isLike = this.checkIfPostIsLiked(likes);
      });
      //  Disliked ?
      this.dataProvider.getdisLike(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((dislikes) => {
        currentPost.dislikes = dislikes.length;
        currentPost.isdisLike = this.checkIfPostIsDislike(dislikes);
      });
      // Commented ?
      this.dataProvider.getComments(currentPost.key).valueChanges().subscribe((comments) => {
        currentPost.comments = comments.length;
        currentPost.isComment = this.checkIfPostIsCommented(comments);
      });
      this.timelineData.unshift(currentPost);
      this.timelineLoaded = true
    }
    return currentPost;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no handy way to do this in my experience.

But since it is a timeline, list changes will always be child add. You can do something like this :

```
  this.timelineData = [];

  this.dataProvider.getTimelinePost().valueChanges().subscribe((posts) => {
    posts.forEach(p => {
      if (!this.timelineData.find(data => data.dateCreated === p.dateCreated)) {
        const elem = this.checkPostData(p);

        // this will put it in front of the list, don't need to reverse
        this.timelineData.unshift(elem);
      }
    })
  });
```

By the way, you shouldn't make subscribe in a subscribe, nor subscribe to create a promise.

Let's consider :

```
const obs1$ = afDb.object(ANYREF).valueChanges();

obs1$.subscribe(data => {
  const obs2$ = afDb.object(data).valueChanges();
  obs2$.subscribe(a => console.log(a));
});
```

This will work but anytime obs1$ does trigger, obs2$ will be "re"subscribed.

ie: if there are 5 changes on obs1$, you will have 5 obs2$' subscriptions.
every new obs2$ changes, you will have 5 times the console.log..., this is a memory leak

A fix maybe using the take(1) operator. This can force the subscription to be triggered once.

```
const obs1$ = afDb.object(ANYREF).valueChanges();

obs1$.subscribe(data => {
  const obs2$ = afDb.object(data).valueChanges();

  // Rxjs 5 way :
  obs2$.take(1).subscribe(a => console.log(a));
  // Rxjs 6 way :
  obs2$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(a => console.log(a));
});
```

obs2$ will always be triggered once and no memory leaks but you won't have "live database data" with obs2$.

a better way :

```
const obs1$ = afDb.object(ANYREF).valueChanges();

// Rxjs 5 way :
obs1$.switchMap(data => afDb.object(data).valueChanges())
  .subscribe(a => console.log(a));
// Rxjs 6 way :
obs1$.pipe(switchMap(data => afDb.object(data).valueChanges()))
  .subscribe(a => console.log(a));
```

With this method you'll keep both observables "live binded" to your database without leak. (Except the one created because it is never unsubscribed).

You may do this :

```
// ionViewWillEnter
const obs1$ = afDb.object(ANYREF).valueChanges();
this.sub = obs1$.pipe(switchMap(data => afDb.object(data).valueChanges()))
  .subscribe(a => console.log(a));

// ionViewWillLeave
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```

If you don't, your subscriptions will be kept alive, whenever you're not on the same page.

Your code seems really complicated to me but if you're a "by example learner", you may refer to this doc : https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. I have to load timeline data after loading the user's friends, it's why i made a promise in my getUserFriends() method. I don't think I have several subscription for my timelinedata, but i have understand why the console.log is trigered twice, it's because the timelineData receive one "child_added" event and one "child_changed" (weird behaviour imo). I will modify the code to be able to withdraw subscriptions.

Comment: that's the whole point of piping observables. You can chain them like promises. Btw if you really want to transform observable to promise there is also the operator .toPromise() (which work with "endable" observable => you need to do obs$.take(1).toPromise() in your case)